# Scraping WEBSITES with nested elements VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to get a value where elemets are nested
EX :

> ```
>     Set myhtml = .Document
> End With
> ```
>
> with myhtml
>       Set List = .getElementsbyTagName("TD").getElementsByTagName("span").getelementbytagname("a")
>
> ```
> For Each l In List
>     If InStr(1, l.innerHTML, "8332103") > 0 Then
>         Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = l.innerText
>         r = r + 1
>     End If
> Next
>
> Set myhtml = Nothing
> Set ie = Nothing
> End Sub
> ```

This procedure gives me back an error (the error is object doesn't support this property or method) here:

> with myhtml
>   set list=
>   .getElementsByTagName("TD").getElementsByTagName("span").getelementbytagname("a")

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is the error number and message?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a typo but this cannot work:

```
with myhtml Set List = .getElementsbyTagName("TD").getElementsByTagName("span").getelementbytagname("a")
```

It should be this:

```
With myhtml
    Set List = .getElementsbyTagName("TD").getElementsByTagName("span").getelementbytagname("a")
End With
```

Comment: the error is object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: the value I need to find is related to this kind of nested elements : <TD class<div id ="8332103"<a class ="MYITEM"</a></div></td>

Comment: You have a typo in the last `GetElementByTagName`, it is missing an `s` at `Element`.  Also, you should edit your question to include the error message.